# Removing personal information from Google when being cyberstalked

Tags: internet

I would like to make a request to the search engines to remove personal information based on the ground of being stalked and that putting personal information can lead to more stalking. Is there any court cases regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, search engines are not required to comply with this request, and will not do so, in the United States. There are narrow circumstances when the E.U. will order search engines to suppress information.